# Match if string contains only ASCII alphanumeric, dash, underscore and dot characters in Perl

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have following Perl script that should write OK if string contains only following characters `a-z` `A-Z` dash `-` underscore `_` or dot `.` and FAIL if string contains any other character. However, it writes OK no matter what I put in string `$ref`.

In this example match should fail because string contains `+` `\` and `/`

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

 print "Content-type: text/html\n\n";   

 $ref = 'abcABCZ01234+56789.htm_abc\/--a'; 

 if ($ref =~ m/[a-zA-Z_0-9\-\.]/) { print "OK\n\n"; }
 else { print "FAIL\n\n"; }

 print "<br>$ref\n\n"; 

1;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your regex matches when it finds first char that satisfies regex class, but to make sure that all chars are inside regex class you have to state that it matches from beginning `^` to the end of the string `\z`,

```
$ref =~ m/^[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+\z/;
```

Comment: Using a character class negation would also work `/[^a-zA-Z_0-9\-\.]/`

Comment: Yes, it would with negation in front of the regex.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to add anchors and quantifier:

```
if ($ref =~ /^[a-zA-Z_0-9.-]+$/) { print "OK\n\n"; }
#            ^              ^^
```

Comment: `$` anchor can also matches before `\n`